# Assign file ownership to a certain user does not work

Tags: chown, ownership

I am trying to assign ownership of a certain file (FILE) to a user (A). I log in as root and run `chown A FILE` but nothing happens. If I add the group option (`chown A:A FILE`), the group is changed but the user is not.

If I try with another user (B: `chown B:A FILE`) it works. Could anyone tell me why a specific user cannot own a file? I have tried in different locations but the result is always the same.

Comment: Who is A? Does A have some special characters in his name?

Comment: try it with the id, instead of the name. to find out the id, use `id <username>`

Comment: A is "bitnam"i and has no special characters. Besides I have tried with the id code obtained after running "id bitnami" and it does not work either. If I follow the same procedure with user B (which is testuser) it does work.

Comment: I do not know if it might have something to do with the fact that I have run a few times a Magento linux installer which creates users and its main user is "bitnami" (the user I am encountering problems with)

Comment: I have deleted A user and created again but the problem persist